# How to get a chronological list of calendar items with a specific Category

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I've Googled, read some posts and documentation, and watched a couple videos, but can't crack this nut.

Here's my use case. For big due dates I make an all-day appointment (so it shows up on the top of my daily view), then tag it with "Big Due Date" (yellow). I want a list of all my big due dates coming up in chrono order.

I have half the solution...I know how to search for all due dates after today.

**start:>today category:(big)**

But when I do that, the search results are separated into two groups and I can't figure out why. It's not alpha. They're all Appointments. It looks like Outlook is sorting by recurrence, but the recurrence features are the same for the first two groups of 6. This separation (see image below/attached) is keeping me from getting a single list by date. I'm fine with the recurring ones being separate.

Please advise!
[pic of what my search result looks like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmcVK.png)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As regards to the two groups of Recurrence:None, I can reproduce the situation on my side. There is also [a thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/list-view-2-different-groups-with-recurrence-none/8d46bc20-5b75-464f-9f64-b32e3db328a6) discussing a similar issue without any solid explanation.

But for your scenario, you may group by "All day event" and then sort by "Start":
[image]